# How to n-times train K Nearest Neighboar (Knn)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn, nearest-neighbor

Is there a way to tell the Knn function in Python how often he should train the model before I predict a possible outcome? From my understanding, if a model is trained more than one time, it is more robust. Or do I get that wrong? From my code it seems that the model is probably one get trained one time:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
neigh.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *k-nearest-neighbor* algorithm isn't a traditional machine learning algorithm that learns by iterations (*epochs*) or additional [decision] trees [...] to slowly converge/adapt, but a model that returns an averaged prediction based on an observation's k nearest (most similar) neighbors. The `fit()` only stores the input training data, defines the distance metric to determine similarity (*nearest*) - by default the *euclidean distance* - and sets `n_neighbors`, the number of neighbors to be considered. A parameter `n_neighbors=1` simply returns a prediction based on the most similar observation already known in the input training data set - otherwise, predictions will be averaged between the k nearest neighbors.

More details regarding the actual implementation of `fit()` and the need to fit a k-nearest-neighbor model in the first place can be found in this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/349842/why-do-we-need-to-fit-a-k-nearest-neighbors-classifier).